# Not getting the correct output for a file when using inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, file-io

So the whole point of my program is to read input from a file and do some calculations and then output the results to the file. 
There are a couple of files involved in this, but for simplicity I will just include the two implementation files for my program. The implementation file "employee" is the base class and the file "merit" is the derived class.

Now for the output I should be getting it in the format of: ID---Salary

I am getting the correct result for the salary, but I am getting the wrong numbers for ID. I know it has to do with the fact that in the merit::print() function, it is printing [merit::ID] and not [employee::ID].

Is there someway that I can make it print out employee::ID and not merit::ID?

The following is the base class file (employee file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "employee.h"
#include "merit.h"


using namespace std;

// The definition of the members functions of the class employee goes here.

void employee::readData(ifstream& inf)
{
    inf >> ID >> Job_class >> Years >> Ed;
}




void employee::print(ofstream& outf) const
{
    outf << ID << setw(15) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << "$ " << sal << endl;
}
```

The following file is the derived class file (merit file):

```
void merit::readData(ifstream& inf)
{
    employee::readData(inf);
    inf >> mer;

}



void merit::print(ofstream& outf) const
{
    outf << ID << setw(15) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << "$ " << salary << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `ID` static?

Comment: @Jerfov2 ID is read from the input file. And then it should be displayed on the input file. The function merit::readData() calls the function employee::readData() which reads the ID from the input file.

Comment: @Jerfov2 ID is private. It was declared in the employee header file.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the right value from the input into `ID`? That may be your problem: reading from the file

Comment: Yes, it reads the right value. If I were to use just the employee file for this program, I would get the correct results. The merit class doesn't print the ID that is read in the employee::readData() function.

Comment: You can't read private member of a base class in derived (use getters to do that). Also, an instance of the base class is required in your derived one (in the merit constructor).

Comment: @Papipone Yeah that was my main error. I just needed to change ID from private to public. Thanks!

Comment: You can also make it protected. This way it will only be accessible through your base class and in your derived ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us your header files where you define the classes so this may not quite be right.  I'm assuming that both `employee` and `merit` both have a member called `ID`.

To access a base class member with the same name as a member in a derived class, just qualify the name.  In your case, use `employee::ID` instead of `ID`.

You've indicated in a comment that `ID` is private in `employee`, so you'll need to use a getter function.  Add something like `int getEmployeeID() const;` to your `employee` class (it can be either protected or public) that would return the ID.  Then call that from you `merit` class to get the employee ID.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.